# php - can only upload image files not audio

Tags: php, mp3, mime-types

Solution

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
require "authenticate.php";
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$message = $_GET['message'];
function uploadfile($dir){
if(!empty($_FILES)){
$url ='';  
$file = ($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "JPG", "JPEG", "PNG", "GIF", "mp3");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "audio/mpeg")
)
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 209715200)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
    $path = $dir . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
    $dir . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $path = $dir . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
    }
    }
else
    {
    $message = "Wrong format";
    }
}
return $path;
}
```

Non Working Code

I have adapted a script I use to upload images into a folder to upload audio but audio files do not save - neither the path into the table or the audio into the folder. 
How do I change this to check the sizes of all files and not just images? getfilesize gives a function does not exist error?

```
<?php
include "connect.php";
require "authenticate.php";
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$message = $_GET['message'];
//function to check for valid image formats
function uploadfile($dir){
if(!empty($_FILES)){
$url ='';  
$file = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);
$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "JPG", "JPEG", "PNG", "GIF", "mp3");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($file["mime"] == "image/gif")
|| ($file["mime"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($file["mime"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($file["mime"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($file["mime"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($file["mime"] == "image/png")
|| ($file["mime"] == "audio/mp3")
)
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
    $path = $dir . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
    $dir . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $path = $dir . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
    }
    }
else
    {
    $message = "Wrong format";
    }
}
return $path;
}
```

Comment: `$file = getimagesize($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);` What's the image size of an mp3 file? What would you expect the value of $file to be after making this call against an mp3 file?

Comment: I don't know. I don't understand how to check both images and other formats.

Comment: Ah, the usual crap w3fools upload handler. "let's pretend the upload always succeeds, do a bunch of stuff with it, then check after the fact if it really did succeed".

Comment: A call to `getimagesize()` for a file returns Boolean `false` if the file isn't an image file (such as your mp3 file) so you can't test the mime type against `$file["mime"]`.... so if `$file` is false, you'll need to rely on `$_FILES["file"]["type"]` for a mime type check against any non-image files.... remembering that the mime type passed to you in $_FILES may not be accurate

Answer (score 2):

try this one:

```
    <?php
include "connect.php";
require "authenticate.php";
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
$message = $_GET['message'];
//function to check for valid image formats
function uploadfile($dir){
if(!empty($_FILES)){
$url ='';  

$allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png", "JPG", "JPEG", "PNG", "GIF", "mp3");
$temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$extension = end($temp);
if ((($file["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($file["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($file["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg")
|| ($file["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")
|| ($file["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png")
|| ($file["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($file["file"]["type"] == "audio/mp3")
)
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 2000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
    {
    if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
    {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
    else
    {
    $path = $dir . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    {
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
    $dir . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
    $path = $dir . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
    }
    }
    }
else
    {
    $message = "Wrong format";
    }
}
return $path;
}
```

Comment: oh! just replace the $file with $_FILES

Comment: i am sure that is work, just replace the audio/mp3 to audio/mpeg (just test it) and make sure that your size is more than 5mb for audio files replace 2000000 to 5242880 or just check it after you checked size. when the size is more than 2000000 $message = "file is big";

Comment: Thanks. I have updated to show the solution. Using mime is the main cause of the problem - similar to what you listed but also declaring $file = ($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]);.

Comment: im just wondered why is needed to declare $file = ($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"]); !?? u can delete this line.

Comment: Yes that is correct it's not needed. Thank you for your help.